# Store textview color from xml on orientation change

Tags: android, xml, colors, textview

I'm just a beginner with android and trying to develope an app with all kind of basis features to get familiar with them. I'm trying to safe a setting of the textview color, chosen by the user. This color is lost when the orientation changes. I've read multiple threads about how to save things for orientation change but all those examples are with strings or boolean etc. 
[saving activity state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

I want to save a value from an xml file. So I have to save a piece of code that sets the color and not a primative datatype.

Part of the code that sets the color:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    switch(item){
        case 0:
            mWelcomeUser.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_color));
            break;
        case 1:
            mWelcomeUser.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_color));
            break;
```

Part of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_color">#A420A0</color>
    <color name="red_color">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="green_color">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="black_color">#000000</color>
    <color name="blue_color">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="grey_color">#828282</color>
</resources>
```

Now I want to save the colorsetting in onPause() and retrieve it in onResume(). But I cant figure this out. I've tried to put it in an int (color) something like this:

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause(); 
    color = mWelcomeUser.getCurrentTextColor();
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mWelcomeUser.setTextColor(color);
}
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can always convert this colour to the ARGB hex value and save that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When orientation changes android pauses the running activity or destroys it.So i set the onPause() as well as onDestroy() methods to hold the text color and in onCreate() and onResume() we will again get the text color.I used SharedPreferences to solve your problem.

I am providing the answer below....

```
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    mWelcomeUser.setTextColor(mPrefs.getInt("currentColor", Color.RED));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

     SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
     mWelcomeUser.setTextColor(mPrefs.getInt("currentColor", Color.RED));
}

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
    ed.putInt("currentColor", mWelcomeUser.getCurrentTextColor());

    ed.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
    ed.putInt("currentColor",  mWelcomeUser.getCurrentTextColor());

    ed.commit();
}
```

Comment: Himanshu, thanks for your answer. This was very helpfull. I thought that every variable in onPause was automatically saved BY onPause itself. But the way you show it is that you have to save the variables IN the onPause method. Thanks again.